# Multiple Joins of ActiveRecord in rails with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, conditional-statements

My active records as follows:

```
    class TemplateItem < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :TemplateGroup_id, :name, :object_type
     belongs_to :TemplateGroup
    end

    class TemplateGroup < ActiveRecord::Base 
     attr_accessible :name, :style, :Widget_id
     belongs_to :Widget
     has_many :TemplateItem
    end

    class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :style
      has_many :TemplateGroup
    end
```

And my query as follows:

```
templateItems=TemplateItem.joins(:TemplateGroup => :Widget).where(:Widget => {:id => w.id})
```

But it shows error.

Please help me how write condition for retriving data based on widget id.

Comment: You want to get all `template_items` of a certain `Widget`?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand, you want to get all `template_items` that belong to a certain `Widget` with some `w.id` "through" `TemplateGroups`?

```
@templateItems=TemplateItem.joins(:templateGroups)
                           .where("templateGroups.widget_id = ?", w.id)
```